# Excel Array Formula showing same results

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm having issues with my array formula showing the same result on all cells. I know it's a simple Index Match, but can someone help me with whats missing to have it return multiple unique values? Most examples I've found only help with returning results within a range, but this is specific to matching text.
`=INDEX(Info2020[[Modêle]:[Catégorie]],MATCH(Criteria,Info2020[Catégorie],0),1)` (obviously Ctl+Shft+Enter to get {})

[image: Picture of cells & results for reference]

Ideal output:

[image: Output]

Comment: You should specify on your title that this question is about Excel, the current title is too generic.

Comment: Please show what you want for output. I'm not clear from your description.

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld, would want all "modele" codes that match the "categorie" to be displayed. I have added an image to the post of the output i'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*would want all "modele" codes that match the "categorie" to be displayed.*

That does not seem to be what is being shown by your `Ideal Output` table.  And I really don't see how your `Ideal Output` is derived from the data you've posted.

But to do what you **write**, you can use a formula like the one below.

You need to convert all of the rows that match your criteria (the `categorie`) and then `INDEX` into the appropriate column.  The `AGGREGATE` function allows you to extract the matching rows in order.

Suggest you break apart the formula, and/or use the formula evaluation tool, to better understand how it is working.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[[Modêle]:[Modêle]],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(Table1[[Catégorie]:[Catégorie]]=J$2)*ROW(Table1[[Modêle]:[Modêle]]),ROWS($1:1))-ROW(Table1[#Headers])),"")
```

and fill down until you get blanks.

**Data**

[image]

**Output**

[image]